# ¿Cómo puedo extraer la parte de array de enteros de este JSON en C#?

Tags: c#, json, array, objeto

Si fueran tan amables me pueden decir ¿Cómo puedo extraer el array de enteros de este JSON? que realmente ya me tiene con dolor de cabeza, lo he intentado de muchas formas. La cuestión es que primero probé con transportarlo a C# como List, luego solo Object y después JObject.

```
{
  "pObjParametros": [{
    "prol_codigo":19,
    "aEVAS_FECHA_INI":"2012-07-11",
    "aeVAS_FECHA_FIN":"2013-08-01",
        "amotivo":[
      12,
      2
    ],
    "aEVAS_CARGO_A":[
      1,
      3
   ]
    }]
}
```

¡Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar al menos cómo lo has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion es utilizar `newtonSoft` para deserializar el `json`. puedes pasarlo a un objeto dinamico o defines el modelo que representa el `json`(recomendable).

Ejemplo:

```
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var lista = results.pObjParametros;
foreach (var element in lista)
{
    var prol_codigo=element.prol_codigo;
    var aEVAS_FECHA_INI=element.aEVAS_FECHA_INI;
    foreach (var motivo in element.amotivo)
    {       
       Console.WriteLine(motivo);
    } 
    //...   
}
```

con modelo

```
public class modelo{
    IEnumerable<ObjParametros> pObjParametros { get; set; }
}
public class ObjParametros
{
   int? prol_codigo { get; set; }
   string aEVAS_FECHA_INI { get; set; }
   string aeVAS_FECHA_FIN { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<int> amotivo { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<int> aEVAS_CARGO_A { get; set; }
}

modelo results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<modelo>(json);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, la cuestión es que justo el segundo no puedo hacerlo porque tengo un DTO general para todo, si tuviera un DTO como lo expones en el segundo punto con modelo ahí si tal vez! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Me dieron esta otra opción de realizar lo solicitado, la cuestión con esta otra forma es q me toca extraer del JToken:

```
 JArray jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray> (JsonConvert.SerializeObject( parametros.pObjParametros));
JToken jObject1 = jObject.FirstOrDefault().SelectToken("amotivo");
```

Comment: Y esto más:
   int number = jObject1.Count();
                int[] enteros =new int[number]; int count = 0;
                int[] array = jObject1.Values<int>().ToArray();